# Symfony3 Assets - different image urls in prod and dev environment

Tags: symfony, assetic

community,

i begin with the code:

**myTwig.html.twig**

```
{% block stylesheets %}
    {% stylesheets filter='?uglifycss' filter='cssrewrite' output='styles/output/main/main.css'
        'styles/css/home.css'
        [...]
    %}<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset_url }}" />{% endstylesheets %}
{% endblock %}
```

**home.css**

```
.mainContainer {
    background: url('../../images/background.png') no-repeat center center;
}
```

If i run `php app/console assetic:dump --env=prod --no-debug`, symfony creates the files `main.css` and `main_home_1.css` in `/web/styles/output/main`. That's right. But the problem is, that the url of the background is different in the two files.

**main.css (prod)**

```
background:url("../images/background.png") no-repeat center center;
```

**main_main_1.css (dev)**

```
background: url("../../../../images/background.png") no-repeat center center;
```

The url in the dev-environment is the correct one. But why are the urls different while they are in the same directory. And how can i solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, i have found a solution: i use now absolute paths.

```
.mainContainer {
    background: url('/images/background.png') no-repeat center center;
}
```